# Tensorflow mismatch of input shape from model restored from SavedModel format

Tags: python, tensorflow

I restored a Tensorflow model from a SavedModel format and added a new layer to the end so I can fine-tune it. But, I realized that the labels to the model from the SavedModel format are of shape (?, 256, 256, 2) whereas my current labels are (?, 256, 256, 4). As a result, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (16, 256, 256, 4) for Tensor 'labels_1:0', which has shape '(?, 256, 256, 2)'
```

Is there any way to somehow modify the inputs of the original model that I restored from the SavedModel format? Or is the only way to manually extract the weights from the original model and assign them to a new version of the same model?

Below is a sample of the code I'm using:

```
meta_graph_def = tf.saved_model.loader.load(
                    sess,
                    [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
                    model_path
                    )
relu_op = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('model/Relu_1:0')
with tf.variable_scope('fine_tune_layer'):
     tune_conv_layer = slim.conv2d(relu_op,
                      output_channels,
                      1,
                      stride=1,
                      rate = 1,
                      padding=('SAME'),
                      activation_fn=None
                      )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your not correctly appending a new layer. What layer did you add? It seems your upsampling the channels somehow. Did you use something like `tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose` or just like `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D`? Can you share some code?

You should have something like:

```
model = tf.saved_model.load("./saved_model") # has output shape (?, 256, 256, 2)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(4)) # (?, 256, 256, 4)
model.compile(loss_function, optimizer)
model.fit(...)
```

Note that above code is rough and just to give you an idea, I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've edited my question with some sample code I'm using. I'm also not using Keras, and simply just TF, so it seems it might be different.

Comment: How do your train your model then? What is "your alternative" to `model.fit()`

Comment: With TF, I can do session.run(optimizer) and that will train the model